# Two strings from a file, converting them into an integer and then subtracting one from another

Tags: java, string, int

In this code I am trying to read two values from different files and then subtract one from the other. The code compiles but when I click the button the console displays an error saying

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5 "

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code that won't allow me to subtract one number from the other

```
breadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  e)
    {
        try{
            String breadStock = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("bread.txt")));
            int breadNumber = Integer.parseInt(breadStock);

            String soldStock = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("soldStock.txt")));
            int sold2Number = Integer.parseInt(soldStock);
            int bNumber = breadNumber - sold2Number;
            System.out.println(bNumber);
        }catch(IOException b){
            b.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: I would say there is a space near 5 (near the number) in the file, remove it or make "5".trim() before converting to integer.

Comment: When you ask Java specific questions, you should add the `java` tag to your question. That way more people will be able to find your question.

Comment: The number 5 is from an Input from a JTextField. When I don't put a space in the JTextField, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Oh I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

NumberFormatException: For input string: "5 "

Remove the space present in that string using trim.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the files? At a guess, I'd say you needed to trim() the string of whitespace before parseInt is called.